# Reuse Elastic Beanstalk resource creating in one cloud formation stack in a second cloud formation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I have an existing cloud formation stack which creates an Elastic Beanstalk app:

```
 Resources:
   EBApplication:
     Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
     Properties:
       ApplicationName: !Ref ApplicationName
       Description: "AWS Elastic Beanstalk Account Balance application"
```

I want to use this resource in another stack, so Im exporting it at the end of the same yaml file:

```
Outputs:
  EBApplicationName:
    Value: !Ref EBApplication
    Export:
      Name: card-balance-EBApplicationName
```

Now in my second cloud formation stack, I was to use the elastic beanstalk resource, Im trying:

```
Resources:
  EBApplication:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !ImportValue 
            'Fn::Sub': 'card-balance-EBApplicationName'
```

But I get an error saying the application name is already being used, as it's trying to create a new Elastic Beanstalk app (with same same) rather than reusing the first one. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
This question here has a similar problem. Essentially I want 2 separate stacks - one for each environment - but these are under the same EB application. It seem the person achieved this, see their comment under the answer [How to create multiple Elasticbeanstalk environments using a single cloudformation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54405115/how-to-create-multiple-elasticbeanstalk-environments-using-a-single-cloudformati/54405274#54405274)

Comment: You can't do what you are trying to do. You basically want to share a resource between two stacks. This isn't supported

Comment: are you sure? you can import an existing resource, so why not this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html

Comment: Copying from your link: The resource to import doesn't belong to another stack in the same Region.

Comment: See this answer, this is what I want to do, same EB application but different stacks for each environment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54405115/how-to-create-multiple-elasticbeanstalk-environments-using-a-single-cloudformati/54405274#54405274

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EB Application resource must be in one and only stack:

```
EBApplication:
  Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
  Properties:
     ApplicationName: !Ref EBApplicationName
     Description: "Application Description"
```

In this stack, you can reference the application in an environment:

```
EBApplicationEnvironment1:
  Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
  Properties:
    ApplicationName: !Ref EBApplication
    EnvironmentName: !Ref EBnvironmentName1
```

This is because, as per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk.html#aws-properties-beanstalk-return-values) Ref returns the resource name.

In another stack you can't reference by resource, but you can by name:

```
EBApplicationEnvironment2:
  Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
  Properties:
    ApplicationName: !Ref EBApplicationName
    EnvironmentName: !Ref EBnvironmentName2
```

With Ref you can reference both another resource (in the same stack only) and a parameter. So for your case, you could in both stacks pass the same application name as a parameter. You don't necessarily need to output the name. (This isn't always the case with CloudFormation. It works here, because you are allowed to define the name and you can reference the resource in the Environment by name. ARNs or ids are needed in other cases. An output will work there).

Also note that the first stack owns the application and environment 1. You will need to delete (when needed) first the second stack and then the first.

Comment: Thanks, Im trying this but when i try to create stack 2 I get: "You must specify either Configuration Template name or Solution Stack name. (Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MissingParameter; "

Comment: These parameters are needed. See some examples in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html#cfn-beanstalk-environment-solutionstackname. The code snippets in the answer weren't meant to be complete.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You can't "reusing the first one" the first one. All modifications to the first EB environment must be performed using the first CFN stack.

In the second stack you can only reference EB [return values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk.html#aws-properties-beanstalk-return-values) in other resources, once you export these values in the first stack.

Comment: Not really sure what to do, firstly, am i outputting from the first stack correctly?

Comment: @Mark You can't use `AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application` in the second stack. It wants to create a duplicate EB application. Thus it errors out.

Comment: What about this answer and the comment below? Ill edit question

Comment: @Mark the other answer is more detailed than mine, thus should be accepted.